# Reading a text file from assets/databases

Tags: android, assets

When I try to read text file from `assets/databases` the program crashes with the error - `java.io.FileNotFoundException: databases/log.txt`

But I can read it from the `assets` directly or from another subfiolder like `assets/data`

Comment: Show us what did you try please.

Comment: Add some code that show how you do it. It is really difficult to answer without knowing what your code looks like

Comment: this the code  <p>   private void readAsset()
    {try {
         
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("databases/log.txt")));
        String line;int i=0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("***",line+"\n");
            i++;
            if (i >10)          break;
        }
        reader.close();

    }  catch (Exception  e)
    {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} </p>